# Ajax in CI not working

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

This is the first time I am working with CI+AJAX+JSON.

I have a controller Admin.php inside controllers directory of Codeigniter. The controller code is as under:

```
public function getmylist()
{
    $users_arr[] = array("sno" => "1", "myname" => "hello");
    echo json_encode($users_arr);
}
```

Then, in views, I have a view with the following code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="mod_countries" id="mod_countries">
  <?php
    if(isset($countrylist))
      foreach($countrylist as $c)
        echo "<option value=" . $c->cname . ">".$c->cname;
  ?>
</select>
```

Then my target select which i need to populate from ajax is

```
<select class="form-control" name="mod_newlist" id="mod_newlist">
</select>
```

My ajax is as under:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mod_countries').change(function(event) {
            var cname = $("select#mod_countries").val();
            alert(cname);
            $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "Admin/getmylist",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {mcname: cname},
                    success: function(res){
                        if(res) {

                            var len=res.length;
                            $("#mod_newlist").empty();
                            for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
                            {
                                var sno=res[i]['sno'];
                                var myname=res[i]['myname'];
                                $("#mod_newlist").append("<option value='" + sno + "'>"+myname+"</option>");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.log('hitting');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(res, status, error) {
                        var err = res.responseText;
                        alert(res.Message);
                        alert(status);
                        alert(error);
                    }

            });
        });
    });
```

When I select an item from the first dropdown list, I get the selected item. Now I expect the second drop downlist to get an item from the controller's code. but, my code goes into error block and alert shows following error messages for each alert line of code:

***undefined***

***parsererror***

***SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0***

Please tell me where I am making a mistake?

Also, please help with regards to how should I return the sno->name pair from model because at lat, i want to populate the new select from database.

Comment: Learn to do some basic debugging, or go read up on that if you don’t have a clue. In this instance, you should start by checking what response you actually got on your AJAX request in your browser dev tools.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the response. This is the first time I am working with CI+AJAX+JSON. I have tried using alerts. The console of browser doesnt say anything. If you are talking about some other debugging strategy that I am not aware of, please let me know, I will be happy to learn that too.

Comment: Dev tools, network panel ... check what the actual server response was for your request.

Comment: The Response is:   I am called[{"sno":"1","myname":"hello"}]   ........   Header gives status code 200 OK  ........ Response headers have content length: 43

Comment: And `I am called` sounds like valid JSON to you? Remove your debug output(?), and output actual JSON and _only that_ ...

Comment: Oh my GOD !!! what a mistake that was. Actually since I am working with this model for the first time, i though json_encode only will be treated as response to ajax, i forgot about this line. Thanks a ton for your kind help. :)

Answer (score 3):

Remove debug/garbage data from response, like `I am called`. If still not work then parse JSON in success as following

```
var res = $.parseJOSN(res);
if(res) {
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing data correctly.
it should be like

```
data:{
  "key" : value
   //use " " to encapsulate string values, only in case of variable You pass value without ""
```

}

I am using CodeIgniter for last two months now. And earlier I had a lot of trouble working with ajax. But my friend suggested me to use AngularJs. It took me just one day to learn Angular and it turned out to be extremely helpful.

It will save a lot of time. And make your work so easy. At first, it may sound difficult but if u spend some time coding then it is going to make your life a lot better. I learned it from JavaTpoint.com and it was very well explained.

Do not try to understand everything at once and practice as you learn.